# Why do my highcharts yaxis tick positions change the min and max of my chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts scatter plot, and I want to customize the locations of the tick marks. I see that I can do this with the `tickPositioner` callback function for each axis. This seems to work fine, but...

1. When I define and use `tickPositioner` on the y-axis, it also seems to reset the chart's max and min to the range of my ticks.
2. When I use it on the x-axis, however, the min and max range stays correct.

Why is there this different behavior between x and y axis?  How can I correctly set the tick positions in my y-axis without affecting the overall range of my axis?

Below is the relevant section of my chart config, and also there's a fiddle demonstrating this at https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/a6mvgbcf/

```
{
  // The positioner in the x axis sets the ticks and preserves the displayed range
  xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function () { return [2, 4, 6, 8] }
  },
  // The positioner in the y axis sets the ticks but changes the displayed range
  yAxis: [{
    tickPositioner: function () { return [2, 4, 6, 8] }
  }],
}
```

[image: Y axis range has changed]

Comment: You mean options [yAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max), it's overwrote when you use tick tickPositioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the X and Y axes is the default value for [endOnTick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick) and [startOnTick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick).

```
  yAxis: [{
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u7gthrnL/

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. This makes total sense now.  I think it would have taken me a while to find this difference!